# how doI display image from images file within my wwwroot on my cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, asp.net-core, razor, wwwroot

The src route is correct. Instead of the image, I get the default 'green hill blue sky' file image on my cshtml

```
<img src="../../wwwroot/images/images.jpg" width="30" height="30" alt="">
```

**What I tried:**

changing it from .jpg to .png

got the same results

**Controller that loads the page:**

basically, all it does is checks if a user is logged on or not by checking the session. Unsure if I should be doing anything else to also display the images. fairly new to this framework.

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("dashboard")]
    public IActionResult Dashboard()
    {
        if(HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("UserId") == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
        }
        ViewBag.loggedinUser = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("UserId");
        HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("DashboardTab", 0);
        return View("Dashboard");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the link to your image.
Try `~` instead of "wwwroot"

Answer (score 1):

Firstly,check if you have `app.UseStaticFiles();` in your Startup.cs.

Then try to use

```
<img src="~/images/images.jpg" width="30" height="30" alt="">
```

the tilde character `~/` points to the `wwwroot`.Refer to the official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-5.0).